How can I view my deleted questions?
Over the years I have asked some very popular questions on Software Engineers (formerly Programmers) which have been closed. I would like to review all of my past questions that have been closed but I can't because my reputation is not high enough. You need 10,000. However, moderators can get at this information.
One of my questions, How do you get past the Analysis to Paralysis when working on a new project? is still visible if you know the question id, which in this case is 155621. Is there a way I can view all my deleted questions, even if I don't know their IDs?

If you go to your profile, click 'Questions', then you can scroll down and click 'Deleted Questions' for yourself. This should bring them all up (though if they've been migrated away to another site I'm not sure if they'll show up).

Thank you. I looked all over yesterday and did not see that link. I see it now.

You can view your own deleted questions and answers.
Specifically, these links will work for the currently logged in user on Software Engineering:

Deleted Questions
Deleted Answers

